# "Unable to access address of buffer" MInecraft 1.10

Tags: 16.04, java, minecraft

I am attempting to run Minecraft 1.10 on Ubuntu 16.04. I've tried using multiple Java versions, specifically JDK 7, Oracle 7, Oracle 8, and Oracle 9, but only 9 managed to launch the actual game. Then, whenever I tried to join a server, I got the error:

> Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to access address of buffer

Now whenever I got to the launcher in other Java versions, game output was blank and I got this error code (for Oracle 8):

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9dgN9x0A)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please put your solution as an answer. That way, you can mark this question as solved! :)

Answer (score 3):

For reference for anyone else having this issue, go to edit profile. In the executable box, put the path to java. (For me, it was /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java check which version you're using) In JVM arguments, I had -Xmx2560M -Xms512M.

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues after upgrading to Ubuntu Mate 18.04. Using the above way did not work. Then I realized it was a problem with openjdk 11 so I switched to openjdk 8. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue, you must install Java 8 JRE, as Minecraft does not work with Java 11.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

Then in your Minecraft launch options, change your Java directory to where your Java 8 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

modify shell script file this:(Example) "**path-to-java-8**" -jar -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
,in my environment path to java-8 is **/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java** .

*this thread already closed. this thread be useful in future.*